# want to get posts of category which have more than 15 comments

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables buckets(category),posts,comment
and i want to get count of post in category which have more than 15 comments

I am trying this query:

```
SELECT buckets.`id`,buckets.`name`,COUNT(comment.`post_id`) AS comment_count 
FROM post
LEFT JOIN `comment` ON comment.`post_id` = post.`id`
INNER JOIN `buckets` ON buckets.`id` = post.`bucket`
GROUP BY comment.`post_id` 
HAVING COUNT(buckets.`id`) > 14 ORDER BY buckets.`id`
```

expected result

```
+----+---------+------------+---------------+
| ID | NAME    | POST_COUNT | COMMENT_COUNT |
+----+---------+------------+---------------+
| 1  | Bucket1 | 3          | 70            |
+----+---------+------------+---------------+
| 2  | Bucket2 | 2          | 80            |
+----+---------+------------+---------------+
| 3  | Bucket3 | 4          | 90            |
+----+---------+------------+---------------+
| 4  | Bucket4 | 0          | 15            |
+----+---------+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: What logic would you use for count the comments, after the first filter you are applying? You will like to `SUM` the comments of all the `post` that belong to the same category?

Comment: Can you add the table definitions and (if possible) the sample data (that should give your expected result) so we can see what you're trying to join? Because I can't see where POST_COUNT comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the query not exactly i want but useful using group_concat

SELECT A.id, A.name, GROUP_CONCAT(A.comment_count SEPARATOR ' , ') AS total_post FROM (SELECT buckets.id,buckets.name,
COUNT(comment.post_id) AS comment_count FROM post INNER JOIN `comment` ON comment.post_id = post.id 
INNER JOIN buckets ON buckets.id = post.bucket 
GROUP BY comment.post_id HAVING COUNT(comment.post_id) > 14) A GROUP BY A.id, A.name

Note->total_post is posts more than 14 comment

id ---- name    -----    total_post
1  ---- H1B     ------    91 , 15 , 19 , 20 , 15 , 15 , 26 , 20 , 79
3  ---- I-140   - ----   28
4  ---- I-134(AP) ----- 40 , 28 , 62
7  ---- MISC     --------   74 , 15

Answer (score 0):

> i want to get count of post in category which have more than 15 comments

Your question is poorly expressed.  In the future keep in mind, it's easier to answer questions about tables if the tables are clearly described.

Evidently you have comments on posts.  Let's get the ones with more 15 or more.  (You said "more than 15", but your query asks for `> 14`.

```
select post_id, count(*) as ncomment from comments
group by post_id
having count(*) > 14
```

Now we can count the posts by category and get the total comments for each

```
select category, count(P.post_id) as npost, sum(N) as ncomment
from  from buckets as P
join (
    select post_id, count(*) as N
    from comments
    group by post_id
    having count(*) > 14
) as C
on P.post_id = C.post_id
group by category
```